# Implicitly declared destructor

Tags: c++11, inheritance, virtual, destructor

If I'm correct, a default destructor is always implicitly declared, unless the user declares it. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor):

> Deleting an object through pointer to base invokes undefined behavior unless the destructor in the base class is virtual

Now, consider this example:

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};
```

Is the implicitly declared destructor `B::~B()` virtual? If not, should I always declare a virtual destructor when using inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the implicitly declared destructor B::~B() virtual?

No, as per [class.dtor/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.dtor#3):

> An implicitly-declared prospective destructor for a class X will have
> the form
>
> ```
> ~X()
> ```

and, naturally, as per [class.dtor/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.dtor#12.sentence-3):

> If a class has a base class with a virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or implicitly-declared) is virtual

---

> If not, should I always declare a virtual destructor when using inheritance?

The C++ Core Guidelines, [C.35](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-dtor-virtual) advices to make base class destructors that are public to be virtual:

> #### C.35: A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and non-virtual
>
> **Reason** To prevent undefined behavior. If the destructor is public, then calling code can attempt to destroy a derived class object
> through a base class pointer, and the result is undefined if the base
> class’s destructor is non-virtual. If the destructor is protected,
> then calling code cannot destroy through a base class pointer and the
> destructor does not need to be virtual; it does need to be protected,
> not private, so that derived destructors can invoke it. In general,
> the writer of a base class does not know the appropriate action to be
> done upon destruction.
>
> [...]
>
> **Note** A virtual function defines an interface to derived classes that can be used without looking at the derived classes. If the
> interface allows destroying, it should be safe to do so.
>
> [...]
>
> **Exception** We can imagine one case where you could want a protected virtual destructor: When an object of a derived type (and only of such
> a type) should be allowed to destroy another object (not itself)
> through a pointer to base. We haven’t seen such a case in practice,
> though.
>
> **Enforcement**
>
> - A class with any virtual functions should have a destructor that is either public and virtual or else protected and non-virtual.

Comment: @mfnx See up updated answer with a link to the C++ Core Guidelines. But generally: if your class is intended to be used polymorphically (e.g. declaring some at least one virtual function) then you should definitely adhere to this advice, but for classes where inheritance is solely intended to be used for implementation inheritance (no polymorphism) than adding a vtable only for the dtor could be considered wasteful.